# Actuator JMS Health Check Return False Positive With Java Configuration

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-artemis

I have run into an issue where the Actuator probe fails for JMS health even though my routes can connect and produce message to JMS. So in short Actuator is saying it is down but it is working.

Tech stack and tech notes:

- Spring-boot: 2.3.1.RELEASE
- Camel: 3.4.1
- Artemis: 2.11.0
- Artemis has been setup to use a user name and password(artemis/artemis).
- Using  `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory` for connection factory.

My route is as simple as chips:

```
  <route id="timer-cluster-producer-route">
            <from uri="timer:producer-ticker?delay=5000"/>
          
            <setBody>
                <groovy>
                    result = ["Name":"Johnny"]
                </groovy>
            </setBody>
            <marshal>
                <json library="Jackson"/>
            </marshal>
            <to uri="ref:jms-producer-cluster-event" />
   </route>
```

**XML Based Artemis Configuration**

With Spring-boot favoring java based configuration I am busy migrating our XML beans accordingly.Thus I took a working beans.xml file pasted into the project and fired up the route and I could send messages flowing and the health check returned OK.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
    <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory"
        class="org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
        <property name="user" value="artemis"/>
        <property name="password" value="artemis"/>
        <property name="connectionLoadBalancingPolicyClassName" value="org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.client.loadbalance.RoundRobinConnectionLoadBalancingPolicy"/>
    </bean>
    <!--org.messaginghub.pooled.jms.JmsPoolConnectionFactory-->
    <!--org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory-->
    <bean id="jmsPooledConnectionFactory"
        class="org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"
        init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
        <property name="maxConnections" value="64" />
        <property name="MaximumActiveSessionPerConnection"
            value="500" />
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
        <property name="connectionFactory"
            ref="jmsPooledConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
        <property name="artemisStreamingEnabled" value="true"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="jms"
          class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
        <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig"/>

    </bean>

<!--    <bean id="activemq"
        class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
        <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig" />
    </bean>-->
    

</beans>
```

**Spring-boot Auto (Black)Magic Configuration**

I then used the application.yaml file to configure the artemis connection by using [this method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/boot-features-messaging.html#boot-features-artemis) as outlined in the Spring-boot documentation. This also worked when my application.yaml file contained the following configuration:

```
artemis:
  user: artemis
  host: localhost
  password: artemis
  pool:
    max-sessions-per-connection: 500
    enabled: true
    max-connections: 16
```

This worked like a charm.

**Brave Attempt At Java Configuration.**

So I then went for gold and tried the Java based configuration as outlined below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:/camel/camel.xml")
public class ClusterProducerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ClusterProducerApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public JmsComponent jms() throws JMSException {
        // Create the connectionfactory which will be used to connect to Artemis
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        cf.setBrokerURL("tcp://localhost:61616");
        cf.setUser("artemis");
        cf.setPassword("artemis");

        //Create connection pool using connection factory
        PooledConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory = new PooledConnectionFactory();
        pooledConnectionFactory.setMaxConnections(2);
        pooledConnectionFactory.setConnectionFactory(cf);

        //Create configuration which uses connection factory
        JmsConfiguration jmsConfiguration = new JmsConfiguration();
        jmsConfiguration.setConcurrentConsumers(2);
        jmsConfiguration.setArtemisStreamingEnabled(true);
        jmsConfiguration.setConnectionFactory(pooledConnectionFactory);

        // Create the Camel JMS component and wire it to our Artemis configuration
        JmsComponent jms = new JmsComponent();
        jms.setConfiguration(jmsConfiguration);
        return jms;
    }
}
```

So when camel starts up I see the following warning logged on start up:

```
020-07-28 12:33:38.631  WARN 25329 --- [)-192.168.1.158] o.s.boot.actuate.jms.JmsHealthIndicator  : JMS health check failed

javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: AMQ229031: Unable to validate user from /127.0.0.1:42028. Username: null; SSL certificate subject DN: unavailable
```

After the 5sec delay the timer kicks in and message are being produced. I logged into the Artemis console and I can browse the messages and can see them being created. However when I run a get on actuator health I see the following:

```
 "jms": {
            "status": "DOWN",
            "details": {
                "error": "javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: AMQ229031: Unable to validate user from /127.0.0.1:42816. Username: null; SSL certificate subject DN: unavailable"
            }
        },
```

This feels like a big of a bug to me.

**Observations about connection pooling implementations.**

I noticed that AMQ connection pooling has been moved into the following maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.messaginghub</groupId>
  <artifactId>pooled-jms</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I thought let me give that a try as well. It show the same behaviour as outlined above with one more interesting thing. When using `org.messaginghub.pooled-jms` as the connection pool(recommended by spring-boot docs as well) the following is logged on startup.

```
2020-07-28 12:41:37.255  INFO 26668 --- [           main] o.m.pooled.jms.JmsPoolConnectionFactory  : JMS ConnectionFactory on classpath is not a JMS 2.0+ version.
```

Which is weird as according to [the official repo](https://github.com/messaginghub/pooled-jms) the connector is JMS 2.0 compliant.

**Quick Summary:**
It appears that actuator does not pick up the credentials of the connection factory when configuring the JMS component via Java. While a work around exists at the moment by using the spring-boot application.yaml configuration it limits the way you can configure JMS clients on Camel.

Comment: The log message you're receiving which says, "JMS ConnectionFactory on classpath is not a JMS 2.0+ version," is coming from the [`JmsPoolConnectionFactory`](https://github.com/messaginghub/pooled-jms/blob/1.1.2/pooled-jms/src/main/java/org/messaginghub/pooled/jms/JmsPoolConnectionFactory.java#L188) (i.e. the pool), not from Camel. It looks like the `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` you're using is from the ActiveMQ 5.x code-base rather than the version from the ActiveMQ Artemis code-base. Artemis supports both, but only the one from Artemis actually supports JMS 2.0.

Comment: Thanks man. Will recheck my dependencies.

Comment: "So in short Actuator is saying it is down but it is working."
thats a false negative then..a false positive would be the other way around..

Comment: @OmarSalem it a false positive. The test is positive it is saying we are positive that JMS is down. However that is not the case. According to google A false positive is an error in data reporting in which a test result incorrectly indicates the presence of a condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So after some digging and [reaching out to the Spring Boot people on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22927), I found what the issue is. When using Java configuration I am configuring the JMS component of Camel with a connection factory. However Spring-boot is completely unaware of this as it is a Camel component. Thus the connection factory used by the JMS needs to be exposed to Spring-boot for it to work.

The fix is relatively simple. See code below:

```java
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
    private ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    @Bean
    public JmsComponent jms() throws JMSException {
        // Create the connectionfactory which will be used to connect to Artemis
        cf.setBrokerURL("tcp://localhost:61616");
        cf.setUser("artemis");
        cf.setPassword("artemis");
        
        // Setup Connection pooling
        PooledConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory = new PooledConnectionFactory();
        pooledConnectionFactory.setMaxConnections(2);
        pooledConnectionFactory.setConnectionFactory(cf);
        JmsConfiguration jmsConfiguration = new JmsConfiguration();
        jmsConfiguration.setConcurrentConsumers(2);
        jmsConfiguration.setArtemisStreamingEnabled(true);
        jmsConfiguration.setConnectionFactory(pooledConnectionFactory);
        // Create the Camel JMS component and wire it to our Artemis connectionfactory
        JmsComponent jms = new JmsComponent();
        jms.setConfiguration(jmsConfiguration);
        return jms;
    }
    /*
       This line will expose the connection factory to Spring-boot.
    */
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
        return cf;
    }
}
```