# Setup and configure Apache Camel in ActiveMQ Artemis for MQTT handling

Tags: apache-camel, mqtt, activemq-artemis

I'm new with ActiveMQ and Apache Camel and have some questions about them and Camel setup.

I'm running ActiveMQ Artemis 2.14.0 ([docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/vromero/activemq-artemis)) and there is MQTT broker running on port 1883.

Client1 is publishing some messages using MQTT and client2 is subscribed and retrieving those messages. Now I would like to add Camel alongside/with ActiveMQ Artemis to be as controller (router) so I can control forwarding of MQTT data or edit it and also to do some MQTT to REST transitions.

I don't know which components of ActiveMQ Artemis and Camel I need to use.

Is Camel already in ActiveMQ Artemis and do I need just to add something in configuration to activate it?

If yes, then I don't know where and which configuration files inside ActiveMQ Artemis I need to edit to setup Camel in it.

When searching on the Internet I see a lot of Java and XML code for Camel configuration, but it's all kinda messy. It's just a bunch of puzzles, and I can't figure out what puzzle to put where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camel does not ship with ActiveMQ Artemis. You have two basic options for configuring Camel. You can download it and configure it independently of the broker. Or you can put your Camel routes into a web application and deploy it to the broker's embedded servlet contain (i.e. Jetty) as demonstrated by the "camel" example shipped with ActiveMQ Artemis (in the `examples/features/standard/camel` directory).

Please note that the documentation for the JMS component will say that you should use the ActiveMQ component if you're using ActiveMQ. This is only valid if you're using ActiveMQ 5.x and not ActiveMQ Artemis.

Also, if you want to use a pooled connection factory you can use [this](https://github.com/messaginghub/pooled-jms) which is an independent project based on the ActiveMQ 5.x JMS pooled connection factory.

Comment: I see. Thank you for giving me some directions. What options to setup Camel do I have if I would use ActiveMQ 5.x? Which version of ActiveMQ (5.x or Artemis) do you recommend for my case?

Comment: Also, tell me please if I'm thinking right about this. In case I go with JMS component, first I would install Camel ([installation example](https://tomd.xyz/camel-tutorial/)), then add JMS component to pom.xml and edit routes in RouteBuilder Java class.

Comment: I updated my answer with another option for deploying Camel routes with ActiveMQ Artemis. In any case, I recommend you use Artemis rather than ActiveMQ 5.x as performance and scaling will better.

Comment: FWIW I'm not a Camel expert. I'm a developer on ActiveMQ. Therefore, I can't give you guidance on how to install Camel and use `RouteBuilder`.

Comment: @JustinBertram the connection pool factory you mention is being reported as not JMS 2.0 compliant by camel. See this question of mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63126305/actuator-jms-health-check-return-false-positive-with-java-configuration/63404584#63404584